# Access Multi Criteria Query to include Blanks/Null records if control is empty (IS NULL)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a multi-criteria query based on several combo boxes where if they are left empty, the result should include all records. I have tried several variations of below but to no use.
I did a lot of searching and found to inculde `OR 'Control Name' IS NULL` but still can't seem to get it working.
I am trying to sum up Revenue grouped by Revenue Identifier (eg. Verified/Unverified/Deleted).

```
SELECT Sum(sTblLineItemMaster.lineItemTotal) AS SumOflineItemTotal, sTblLineItemMaster.lineItemStatus

FROM sTblActivityMaster INNER JOIN sTblLineItemMaster ON sTblActivityMaster.actID = sTblLineItemMaster.lineItemActID

WHERE 
((sTblActivityMaster.actTargetYear=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchYear] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchYear] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actTargetMonth=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchMonth] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchMonth] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actTargetWeek=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchWeek] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchWeek] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actCategory=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchCategory] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchCategory] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actCustOwner=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchOwner] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchOwner] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actRegion=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchCoordinatorRegion] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchCoordinatorRegion] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actMode=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchMode] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchMode] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actCreator=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchCoordinator] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchCoordinator] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actSection=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchSection] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchSection] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actProject=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchProject] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchProject] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actRevenueBookStatus=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchRevenue] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchRevenue] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actVerificationStatus=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchVerification] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchVerification] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actAcceptanceStatus=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchAcceptance] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchAcceptance] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actKPIStatus=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchKPI] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchKPI] Is Null) AND
(sTblActivityMaster.actInvoicingStatus=[Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchInvoicing] Or [Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchInvoicing] Is Null))

GROUP BY sTblLineItemMaster.lineItemStatus;
```

Can anyone please check if syntax is OK or if any other modification is needed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using ComboBoxes to get the search criteria and the empty combo boxes return a "" and not NULl, so the query wasn't returning the results.
So what I did was that when search button is pressed to run the query, I set all empty or "" comboboxes to NULL in VBA. That did the trick and results appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it this way:

```
sTblActivityMaster.actTargetYear=Nz([Forms]![frmActivityList]![cmbSearchYear],sTblActivityMaster.actTargetYear)
```

That makes it simpler by just having a series of `AND` without mixing `OR` and having to deal with the parenthesis mess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not get a chance to implement it as I was able to solve it in another way without changing the query.
Solution:
As I am using ComboBoxes to get the search critera, the empty combo boxes return a "" and not NULL. So when the search button is pressed to run the query, I set all empty or "" comboboxes to NULL in VBA. That did the trick.